# ansible switch user to other than sudo

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, sudo

On my Linux machine, there are three user levels in the system.

```
- base_user
- higher_user
- root
```

I remotely connect via SSH, to the machine at base_user level. 
My ssh key setup lets me login as base_user automatically. 
then I want to change as higher_user which does not have sudo privilege.
From ansible document(http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html), become and become_user require sudo on base_user in order to become higher_user. 
I do not want to let higher_user or base_user to have sudo privilege.

Is there any workaround to just purely do following in ansible?

```
1. login as base_user with ssh key setup
2. switch user to higher_user with password input
```

Comment: What do you call "sudo user"? A user that can sudo root? Anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in your sudoers file will allow base_user to use sudo to run commands as higher_user.  It won't allow base_user to run commands as root or any other user.

```
base_user   ALL=(higher_user) ALL
```

From there you can use `become` and `become_user` in your playbook.

```
- hosts: some_host
  become: True
  become_user: higher_user
  tasks:
...
```

When you run `ansible-playbook` you will need to provide base_user's password with `--ask-become-pass` (`-K`).